# Required Field Missing Error on Apex Trigger Test in Salesforce

Tags: testing, triggers, salesforce, apex

I am failing my apex code test with the following error:

"System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Opportunity__c]: [Opportunity__c]
Stack Trace: Class.Integromat_GetAuroraArrayInfoTest.testTrigger: line 68, column 1"

Arrays_from_Aurora__c is a Child Relationship to Opportunity.  Opportunity__c exists both as an opportunity field as well as an Arrays_from_Aurora__c field.

How do I fix this?  Thank You!

Here is my test:

```
@isTest
public class Integromat_GetAuroraArrayInfoTest {

static SObject mock(String sobjectName) {
    SObjectType t = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectName);

    SObject o = t.newSobject();

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> m = t.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for (String fieldName : m.keySet()) {
       
        DescribeFieldResult f = m.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
        if (!f.isNillable() && f.isCreateable() && !f.isDefaultedOnCreate()) {
            if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Boolean) {
                o.put(f.getName(), false);
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Currency) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 0);
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Date) {
                o.put(f.getName(), Date.today());
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.DateTime) {
                o.put(f.getName(), System.now());
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Double) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 0.0);
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Email) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 'foo@foo.com');
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Integer) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 0);
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Percent) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 0);
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Phone) {
                o.put(f.getName(), '555-555-1212');
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.String) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 'TEST');
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.TextArea) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 'TEST');
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Time) {
                o.put(f.getName(), System.now().time());
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.URL) {
                o.put(f.getName(), 'http://example.com');
            }
            else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.PickList) {
                o.put(f.getName(), f.getPicklistValues()[0].getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

@isTest static void testTrigger() {
    SObject o = mock('Arrays_from_Aurora__c');
        

    Test.startTest();
    insert o;
    update o;
    delete o;
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(200, Webhook.response.getStatusCode());
   
    }}
```

Comment: Line 68 is " insert o;"

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. There's a required field called `Opportunity__c` on the object `Arrays_from_Aurora__c`, and your code is not populating it.

The data mocking framework you are using doesn't populate relationship fields at all. It's not going to work for the majority of Salesforce data models for that reason. You'll need to either manually construct all of the data required, or use a more sophisticated mocking framework that allows you to construct relationships between records.